# Detection of material

Tags: python, opencv

Hi I'm working on detection of material like this below:

[image]

I have try to detect the brown crystal and make circle detection or rectangular but still there are so many noises

I have try to use hsv like this below:

```
canny = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_red = np.array([15,10,50])
upper_red = np.array([150,110,160])
edged = cv2.inRange(canny, lower_red, upper_red)
```

... or using this. But no one help.

```
imgray= cv2.GaussianBlur(imgray, (7,7),0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 237, 28, 37)
edged = cv2.Canny(imgray, 5, 5)
edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=1)
edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=1)
```

Is there anything that I can do?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you are looking for is a morphological close operation.

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = Image.open('./n2JCm.png')

img_np = np.array(img)

img_np_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(AA,cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)

plt.figure(figsize=(35,35))
plt.imshow(cv2.morphologyEx(img_np_rgb,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,np.ones((2,2)),iterations=10))
```

You'll get something that looks like this:
[image]

That should get rid of your little specks of dirt.

I would also try clustering using KMeans or DBScan

```
from sklearn import cluster

model = cluster.KMeans(3)

plt.figure(figsize=(35,35))
plt.imshow(model.fit_predict(img_np_rgb.reshape((-1,3))).reshape(img_np_rgb.shape[:2]))
```

[image]

or some other clustering algorithm.

Comment: Hi Aviv...Thank You....Whats you mention are new things for me....Many thanks for your answer..I will check the clustering algorithm...